# How to use Leaflet Fullscreen in Vue2Leaflet

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, fullscreen

Does anyone have example of how to integrate [Leaflet Fullscreen](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.fullscreen) with [Vue2 Leaflet](https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet)

I use Vue2Leaflet in a component (loaded thru npm), and added the CDN link to the Fullscreen js in index.html.  But when fullscreen js loaded, it couldn't find a reference to Leaflet as its not loaded yet.  So I'm not sure how to use them in proper order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to access the map object with `this.$refs.mymap.mapObject` and add the control in the `mounted` hook.

First add a `ref` attribute to the `<l-map />` element:

```
<l-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center" ref="mymap">
  ...
</l-map>
```

Then add the control in the `mounted` hook:

```
mounted() {
  const map = this.$refs.mymap.mapObject;
  map.addControl(new L.Control.Fullscreen());
}
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zpkhjt6u/)

If you are using webpack, it's a bit different:

1) Install with `npm install leaflet-fullscreen --save`

2) Import the `js` and `css` files in your `main.js` file (app entry point) or use `<script>` in `index.html`:

```
import 'leaflet-fullscreen/dist/leaflet.fullscreen.css';
import 'leaflet-fullscreen/dist/Leaflet.fullscreen';
```

3) In your component, use `window.L` instead of `L`:

```
mounted() {
  const map = this.$refs.mymap.mapObject;
  map.addControl(new window.L.Control.Fullscreen());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, but I'm using webpack and when compiling, I got this error

_[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_leaflet___default.a.Control.Fullscreen is not a constructor"_

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think you need to replace `L` by `window.L`

Answer (score 0):

For those using Nuxt with vue2-leaflet (and don't want to use a plugin but instead import it locally for performance reasons), this is how you can do it:

npm install leaflet-fullscreen

Require the needed files, create a method that runs when the map loads.

```
         <l-map
                @ready="LoadFullscreen()"
                ref="myMap"
              >
        
        <script>
let LMap,
  LTileLayer,
  LMarker,
  LPopup,
  LIcon,
  LControlAttribution,
  LControlZoom,
if (process.client) {
  require("leaflet");
  ({
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LMarker,
    LPopup,
    LIcon,
    LControlAttribution,
    LControlZoom,
  } = require("vue2-leaflet/dist/vue2-leaflet.min"));
  require("leaflet-fullscreen/dist/leaflet.fullscreen.css");
  require("leaflet-fullscreen/dist/Leaflet.fullscreen");
}
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

... export defaults etc
... set your components

```
methods: {
LoadFullscreen() {
  if (!process.server) {
    const map = this.$refs.listingsMap.mapObject;
    map.addControl(
      new window.L.Control.Fullscreen({
        position: "topright",
      })
    );
  }
},
```

},